# Approximation for a series involving the derivative of a Jacobi theta function

Tags: theta-functions, theta-series

I’ve considered the diffusion equation $$\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}=\frac12 \frac{\partial^2 f(x,t)}{\partial x^2}$$ with the conditions $f(x,0)=\delta(x)$ and $f(-1,t)=f(1,t)=0\ \forall t>0$ and I’ve found the solution $$f(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos\left[ \left( n+\frac12 \right)\pi x \right] e^{-\frac12 (n+1/2)^2\pi^2 t}$$then I’ve considered the function$$\Lambda(t)=-\frac d{dt}\int_{-1}^1f(x,t)dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(n+\frac12\right)\pi\ e^{-(n+1/2)^2\pi^2 t/2}=\\=\frac\pi2\left(e^{-\frac{\pi^2} 8t}-3\,e^{-\frac{9\pi^2} 8t}+5\,e^{-\frac{25\pi^2} 8t}-\ldots\right)=\frac \pi 4 \vartheta_1'(0,e^{-\pi^2 t/2})$$where $\vartheta_1'(u,q)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u}\vartheta_1(u,q)$ and $$\vartheta_1(u,q)=2\,q^{1/4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n q^{n(n+1)}\sin\left[\left(2n+1\right)u \right]$$is a Jacobi theta function.
It turns out that $$\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\Lambda(t)}{g(t)}=1$$ where $g(t)=\sqrt{\dfrac2{\pi t^3}}e^{-\frac1{2t}}$ (so *Mathematica* says and the approximation is very good as the values of $\Lambda$ and $g$ differ for less than $1\%$ for $0<t<0.7$), but I don’t know how to prove it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In general for such questions on theta functions, it is a good idea to keep their [modular properties](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.7#viii) in mind. Of course, the Poisson summation of the accepted answer is at the heart of these properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your $\Lambda$ as
$$\Lambda(t)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{-\infty}^\infty f(n),$$
where
$$f(x)=\pi(x+1/2)\sin\pi(x+1/2)\exp\left(-\pi^2(x+1/2)^2t/2\right)=y\sin y\,e^{-ty^2/2},$$
where $y=\pi(x+1/2),$ and $t>0$.
Then use [Poisson's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula)
$$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(2\pi n),$$
where
$$\hat{f}(s)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-isx}dx$$
is the Fourier transform. This Fourier transform can be explicitly computed:
$$\hat{f}(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}t^{-3/2}e^{is/2}\left((s/\pi+1)e^{-(s/\pi+1)^2/(2t)}-(s/\pi-1)e^{-(s/\pi-1)^2/(2t)}\right).$$
The trick is that in the Fourier transform your parameter $t$ will stand in the denominator of the exponent, so the series $\sum\hat{f}(n)$ will be asymptotic to the sum of $3$ terms (with $n=0,\pm1$), z when $t\to 0$,
$$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(2\pi n)\sim \hat{f}(0)+\hat{f(2\pi)}+\hat{f}(-2\pi)\sim 2\hat{f}(0)=2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t^3}}e^{-1/(2t)},\quad t\to 0+,$$
and since $\Lambda(t)$ is $1/2$ of this sum, we obtain
the answer that wrote.

(In the computation of Fourier transform, I started with the $e^{-y^2/(2t)}$, and then used the transformation rules
of Fourier transform: multiplied my function on $y$, then on $\sin y$, and then scaled by $\pi$ and added $1/2$ to the argument).

Remark. This approximation is related to the famous computation of the [age of Earth](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/ageofearth.pdf) by Lord Kelvin. Roughly speaking, the series corresponds to the exact solution for the heat equation inside the spherical Earth, while the asymptotics corresponds to the
[flat Earth approximation](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/ageofearth2.pdf). It is unclear from his papers on the subject, whether Kelvin knew the exact solution and Poisson's formula.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I've noticed that also $\hat f(2\pi)$ and $\hat f(-2\pi)$ contain a term $e^{-1/(2t)}$, but adding all $e^{-1/(2t)}$ terms and dividing by $2$, as $\Lambda$ is half the summation of $f(n)$, yields the required result. Thank you again!

Comment: @Giovanni Agapito: Thanks, I corrected my computation .